# Taking the average age an employee is hired with Sqlite3(python)

Tags: sqlite

I need to subtract everyone's years worked from their age, and take the average. My final answer should be a whole number to represent the average age when hired.

Here is my code

```
select HireDate,
CASE
    WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) > strftime('%m', date(BirthDate))
    THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
    
    WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) = strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN strftime('%d', date('now')) >= strftime('%d', date(BirthDate))
            THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
            
            ELSE strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
        END
        
    WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) < strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
 
 END AS 'age',
CASE
    WHEN 1>0
    THEN (strftime('%Y', date(HireDate)) - strftime('%Y', date('now')))
END AS 'yw'
from Employee
```

This gives me Employee's date hired, age, years worked:

[image]

Does anyone know why subtracting the two cases isn't working?

Comment: That's an extremely complicated way to get the difference in years. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918511/difference-of-year-between-two-date for simpler ways. Then round down.

Comment: Where is the part of the query that tries to subtract them? Put your above query in a CTE or subquery, then use `SELECT AVG(age-yw) FROM cte` to get the average.

Comment: Thank you Barnar, I ended up going about the simpler way. On the bright side, going the long way and trying to find a way to solve it gave me a better understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT HireDate,
    CASE
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) > strftime('%m', date(BirthDate))
        THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
        
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) = strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN
            CASE
                WHEN strftime('%d', date('now')) >= strftime('%d', date(BirthDate))
                THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
                
                ELSE strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
            END
            
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) < strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
     
     END AS age,
    CASE
        WHEN 1>0
        THEN (strftime('%Y', date(HireDate)) - strftime('%Y', date('now')))
    END AS yw
    from Employee
)
SELECT avg(age-yw) AS answer FROM cte1;
```

This overcomes the age and yw columns not found.

Here's a working example that closely (enough) reflects the data:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (birthdate TEXT, hiredate TEXT);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES
    ('1980-06-01','2024-05-01')
    ,('1983-09-01','2024-08-14')
    ,('1995-09-01','2024-04-01')
    ,('1969-09-01','2025-05-03')
    ,('1995-09-01','2025-10-17')
    ,('1992-09-01','2026-01-02')
    ,('1989-09-01','2026-03-05')
    ,('1997-09-01','2026-11-15')
;
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT HireDate,
    CASE
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) > strftime('%m', date(BirthDate))
        THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
        
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) = strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN
            CASE
                WHEN strftime('%d', date('now')) >= strftime('%d', date(BirthDate))
                THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate))
                
                ELSE strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
            END
            
        WHEN strftime('%m', date('now')) < strftime('%m', date(BirthDate)) THEN strftime('%Y', date('now')) - strftime('%Y', date(BirthDate)) -1
     
     END AS age,
    CASE
        WHEN 1>0
        THEN (strftime('%Y', date(HireDate)) - strftime('%Y', date('now')))
    END AS yw
    from Employee
)
SELECT */*,avg(age-yw) AS answer*/ ,(SELECT avg(age-yw)FROM cte1) FROM cte1; /* note adapted to show all data not just average (so avg repeated) */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee /* cleanup */
```

and the result (note comment re showing all data):-

[image]

- *Consider the comments re over-complex*

Comment: Thank you Mike, this works great! I spoke with my learning assistant about the same problem and she cut the code down to this. I had no idea that sqlit3 could use the arithmetic on the dates and birthdays.

SELECT AVG(HireDate - BirthDate)
FROM Employee

Answer (score 0):

if anyone in the future is trying to find say the average hire date of an employee from HireDate and Birthdate columns, the best answer I've seen is

```
SELECT AVG(HireDate - BirthDate)
FROM Employee
```